# Crash while using array of function pointers in a structure

Tags: c, structure, function-pointers

When I use an array of function pointers in a structure, the program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*FUNCPTR)(void);

void Function_1()
{
    printf(" In Function_1 \n");
}
void Function_2()
{
    printf(" In Function_2 \n");
}

typedef struct St_FUNCPTR
{
    FUNCPTR xxx[2];  
}ST_FUNCPTR;

FUNCPTR fnptr1[2] =
{
    Function_1,
    Function_2
};

ST_FUNCPTR fnptr =
{
    fnptr1 

};

/* The intention is to call Function_1(); through array of function 
   pointers in the structure. */  

int main()
{
    // to call Function_1();
    fnptr.xxx[0]();
    return 0;
}
```

If the structure is defined like below, it works fine.

```
ST_FUNCPTR fnptr =
{
    {Function_1,Function_2},
};
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: I hope your actual code is more complicated than this, since the `St_FUNCPTR` struct seems to unnecessarily complicate things and you can do the exact same thing by using `fnptr1` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bets are here:

```
ST_FUNCPTR fnptr =
{
    fnptr1 

};
```

What you are trying to do is initialize structure, which element is an array with an array. fnptr1 is an array of pointers to function.
With your edit it's for sure. You can't initialize array with another array like you cant say that int a1[10]=int b[10].
For clarification: fnptr1 here is pointer constans to pointer to function.And it goes to xxx[0] being converted to pointer to the function by the way. 
What code does next, it takes address of that pointer, `fnptr.xxx[0]` , treats it like a pointer to function and calls it with (). But theres no function under that address, just pointer to the function, so there's a crash.

Comment: There should have been a compiler warning about the wrong kind of pointer being used in the initializer. Don't ignore warnings! And if you're going to ask questions about your code, you should always mention what warnings you got - especially if you didn't understand why you got them.

Comment: @Zubergu    Yes,there was warning saying initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|  understood the problem as explained in Zubergu's post.     But didn't understand one more warning for same statement  warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]|

Comment: See how your working initializer `ST_FUNCPTR fnptr = { {Function_1,Function_2} };` has 2 levels of braces? And the one that generates the warning has only 1 level? The outer braces represent the struct and the inner braces represent the array. Omitting braces is allowed, but usually not a good idea. That's why it warned you.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Consider adressing those comments to the author of the question and code.